# ReactJS: How to make button background colour change when the text inside it is a certain value

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux

I am working on a React application and I am using Redux to store the state. I have the following code.

button.component.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

import './button.styles.scss';

export default ({ children, secondary, className, ...props }) => (
    <button className={`button ${className ? className : ''} ${secondary ? 'secondary' : ''}`} {...props}>{children}</button>
)
```

button.styles.scss:

```
.button {
    background-color: #222222;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #222222;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;

    &:active, &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    &:hover {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #222222;
    }

    &.secondary {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #222222;
        border: 1px solid #222222;

        &:hover {
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: #222222;
        }
    }
}
```

edit-menu-button.component.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Button from '../button/button.component';

class EditMenuButton extends React.Component {

    state = {
        text: "Edit Menu"
    }

    changeText = () => {
        const { text } = this.state;
        if(text === "Edit Menu") {
            this.setState({text: "Save Edits"});
        } else {
            this.setState({text: "Edit Menu"});
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { text } = this.state;

        return (
            <Button onClick={ () => { this.changeText()} }>{text}</Button>
        );
    }
}

export default (EditMenuButton);
```

menu.component.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import MenuCategory from '../../components/menu-category/menu-category.component'
import NewCategoryButton from '../../components/new-category-button/new-category-button.component';
import EditMenuButton from '../../components/edit-menu-button/edit-menu-button.component';

import './menu.styles.scss';

const MenuPage = props => {

    return (
        <div className='menu-page'>
            {props.menu ? props.menu.map(category => <MenuCategory key={category._id} {...category} />) : null}
            <div className='edit-menu-buttons'>
                <div className='menu-button'>
                    {props.currentUser ? <NewCategoryButton /> : null}
                </div>
                <div className='menu-button'>
                    {props.currentUser ? <EditMenuButton /> : null}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    currentUser: state.user.currentUser,
    menu: state.menu
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MenuPage);
```

For my `EditMenuButton` component, I have a function that changes the button text when the button is clicked. When the text in the button is 'Save Edits', I would like the background colour of the button to be `#6ad0d4` instead of `#222222`.

I know that I could add a class to my button such as `'save-edits-true'`, and then apply the style using this class. However, I am not sure how I can go about dynamically adding a class to my `Button` component when the text inside the `EditMenuButton` component button is 'Save Edits'.

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: You should have a look at styled components. You can modify the style of a styled component just by passing props, no need to change the className

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inline-style

Try the in-text demo:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState("Save Edits");
  const inputHanlder = e => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={inputHanlder} value={input} />
      <br />
      Change the button background color based on it's text content
      <br />
      <button
        style={{
          backgroundColor: input === "Save Edits" ? "#6ad0d4" : "#222222",
          color: "white"
        }}
      >
        {input}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this simple change - 
`<Button onClick={ () => { this.changeText()} } 
backgroundColor={this.state.text === "Save Edits" ? '#6ad0d4': ''#222222''}>{text}</Button>`

and use that props in button component to dynamically change the background color.